# Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly python

Tags: python, string, sockets, byte

I made a program to open web pages using `python 3.5` by using socket library. first, i prompt user to enter URL and then I `split()` that URL to extract host name for `connect()` method. But I am getting the following error which points towards my get request command:

> cmd ='GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode() TypeError: Can't
>   convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Following is my code:

```
import socket

user_url = input("Enter url: ")
host_name = user_url.split("/")[2]
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
cmd ='GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
   data = mysock.recv(512)
   if (len(data) < 1):
      break
   print (data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

Comment: haha: `cmd =('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n').encode()`

Comment: `(cmd ='GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n').encode()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd ='GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
       ^         ^                ^
      str       str          bytes
```

this line encodes just the last part, and mixing string type with bytes type isn't possible, which explains the error.

You want to encode the whole string for instance like this:

```
cmd = ('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n').encode()
```

Better yet, use `format` to avoid confusion and string addition:

```
cmd ='GET {} HTTP/1.0\n\n'.format(user_url).encode()
```